# Create new actions without being influenced by NLA

Tags: animation

I'll start of by saying that the action- and NLA- editors are both pretty new to me.

I have so far been able to create a walkcycle that I can loop through as the character moves around in the scene. Now I want to add a new loop for when he is stading still. It's really just going to be him standing in place breathing, not anything more.

I created a new action that I called "Idle" and I would now like to make the new animation. This becomes tricky when the character keeps moving around the scene as I have previously made him do.

My question is this;
Is it possible to create new actions without being influenced by all the stuff I've already done?
Like maybe have a seperate scene for creating new actions or an option to temporarily disable all animations and setting the character to the center whilst I make a new action. something like that.

The only other way I can think of is if I had made all my actions before I started making the actual animation but that is a bit too late at this point.

Answer (score 1):

In the NLA editor you have nla tracks under your rig and there are speakers icons that allow you to mute your tracks.
I'm making the same thing right now with my character.[image]

Comment: Oh... I honestly thought those had to do with sound. Like for when you need to time sound to your animation and the other way around. Thanks a lot :)